Generalization of the generalization of the evasiveness conjecture
The generalized evasiveness conjecture (Aanderaa, Rosenberg, Karp, Kahn, Saks, Sturtevant) states that any non-constant, monotone ($x\le y \Rightarrow f(x)\le f(y)$, weakly symmetric Boolean function is evasive.
My question is about the below further generalization.
Assume that we have two disjoint sets, $A$ and $B$ and a monotone Boolean function $f$ that maps from $\{0,1\}^{A \cup B}$, or equivalently by considering characteristic functions, from the subsets of $A\cup B$, to $\{0,1\}$ such that

$f(\emptyset)=0$,
$f(A)=f(B)=1$,
For any $a,a'\in A$ there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(a)=a'$, $\sigma(A)=A$, $\sigma(B)=B$ and $f\equiv f\circ \sigma$,
For any $b,b'\in B$ there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(b)=b'$, $\sigma(A)=A$, $\sigma(B)=B$ and $f\equiv f\circ \sigma$.


Is it true that such an $f$ is always evasive?

Of course, we could take even more sets, or remove the disjointness condition, but this is the first interesting case.

Relevant background: https://tcsmath.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/lecture-7-the-evasiveness-conjecture/

Not bad, though I prefer this one, maybe you've heard of it :) https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0205031v1
